# The instrument that measures the consumption of water

Tags: word-choice, terminology, translation

What is the English name of [this instrument](http://images.globes.co.il/Images/NewGlobes/big_image/2012/972588%5B6.jpg), that measures the consumption of water?

In Hebrew we call it "Sheon Mayim" (literally: "water clock"), but in English, [water clock is a clock for measuring time, based on the flow of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_clock).

Another Hebrew name is "Mad Mayim" (literally: "water measurer"), but in English [water measurer is an insect](http://www.wildlifetrusts.org/species/water-measurer).

Google Translate says "Hydrometer", but [a Hydrometer is an instrument for measuring some properties of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrometer).

Comment: That's a `water meter`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_metering There's a different group that may be better for questions like this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I tried everything but this :)

Comment: A [klepsydra](http://www.answers.com/topic/klepsydra) or [clepsydra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clepsydra), from Gk  κλέπτειν 'to steal' + ὕδωρ 'water' > 'water thief'. Klept- as in _kleptomania_, and hydr- as in _hydroelectric_ (in Greek /h/ sometimes alternated with /s/).

Comment: @JohnLawler, the s in _clepsydra_ is not from the ‘water’ part of the word: it’s from the aorist stem of κλέπτω, which is of course κλεψ-. The initial /h/ is simply suppressed here (as always in compounds, since aspiration can only occur lexeme-initially). There is no s-initial variant of the word ὕδωρ: its initial aspiration is purely automatic and unetymological. (Thankfully—‘swater’ wouldn’t be a very nice word for it, and we’d have to be drinking svodka and swisk(e)y …)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about the verb forms of κλέπτειν. s/h alternations are common enough, but this looked odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a water meter.

[image]

In a lot of part of America you will see a bigger sized "green" meter that is checked every so often by the water company so they can send bills.  This is a typical older style or one found in larger multi-unit buildings.